# Problems With GUI Handles - Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am building a `gui` in Matlab programatically which plots data using a gui `listbox` in conjunction with the `scatter` function.

My main script that adds the `axes` object component to the `figure` is as follows:

```
%% create figure
fig_h = figure;
set(fig_h, 'Position', [100, 100, 1049, 895]);

%% create plot
figure
axes_h = axes('Position',[0.1 0.3 0.4 0.5], 'XLim', [-4 4], 'YLim', [-4 4]);
xlabel(axes_h, 'Valence', 'FontSize', 12, 'FontWeight', 'bold');
ylabel(axes_h, 'Arousal', 'FontSize', 12, 'FontWeight', 'bold');
grid('on');

%% create panel
panel_position = [0.55 0.3 0.32 0.5];
panel_h = uipanel('Title','Plot Music','FontSize',12,'BackgroundColor','white','Position',panel_position);

%% create listbox
list_position = [0.2 0.3 0.6 0.6];
list_h = uicontrol('Parent',panel_h,'Style','Listbox','String',tracks,'units', 'normalized','Position',list_position, 'callback', {@guiList, axes_h, valence, arousal});

%% create toggle button
toggle_position = [0 0 0.2 0.1];
toggle_h = uicontrol('Parent',panel_h,'Style', 'togglebutton', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', toggle_position, 'String', 'Hold', 'callback', @guiToggle);
```

The `listbox_h` 'callback' pertains to this function:

```
function guiList(list_h, evt, axes_h, valence, arousal)

val = get(list_h, 'value');
a = 40;
x = valence;
y = arousal;

for i=1:17
    if i == val
        scatter(axes_h, x(i), y(i), a,'MarkerEdgeColor',[0 .5 .5], 'MarkerFaceColor',[0 .7 .7],'LineWidth',1.5)
        axis(axes_h, [-4 4 -4 4])
        grid on
    end
end

end
```

I am a little confused because I am having to mirror everything that the original `axes_h` had setup e.g. the `XLim`, `FontSize`, etc. when the function above keeps executing.  For instance, with the code as it is, the X and Y labels both disappear when `guiList` executes.  I was hoping I could set everything up in `axes_h` and then use the `scatter` function to plot the data providing I provide it with the `axes_h` handle?

I am also having problems with my `guiToggle` function:

```
function guiToggle(toggle_h, evt, scatter_h)

button_state = get(toggle_h,'Value');

if button_state == 1
    hold(scatter_h, 'on');
elseif button_state == 0
    hold(scatter_h, 'off');
end

end
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error in guiToggle (line 6)
hold(scatter_h, 'on');
```

Comment: [`hold`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html) works with axes. So it should be `hold(axes_h,'on');` ( you may need to pass `axes_h` in or `axes_h=gca;`. However I think `hold on` should work as well

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the above seem to hold the plot when executed within my `guiToggle` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an empty scatter plot when you set up your `axes`:

```
%% create plot
figure
axes_h = axes('Position',[0.1 0.3 0.4 0.5], 'XLim', [-4 4], 'YLim', [-4 4]);
scatter_h = scatter(axes_h, [],[],40, 'MarkerEdgeColor',[0 .5 .5], 'MarkerFaceColor',[0 .7 .7],'LineWidth',1.5)
xlabel(axes_h, 'Valence', 'FontSize', 12, 'FontWeight', 'bold');
ylabel(axes_h, 'Arousal', 'FontSize', 12, 'FontWeight', 'bold');
grid('on');
```

Then pass the handle to the scatter plot to `guilist` and set the `XData`, `YData` and `SizeData` properties:

```
function guiList(list_h, evt, scatter_h, valence, arousal)
    val = get(list_h, 'value');
    a = 40;
    x = valence;
    y = arousal;
    for i=1:17
        if i == val
            set(scatter_h, 'XData', x(i), 'YData', y(i), 'SizeData', a);
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks - that makes more sense now. I should probably post this as a separate question, but I was wondering as to how I would draw two 3px black lines vertically and horizontally over my scatter plot programatically, so the plot has a 'cross' centered at 0? Also, how can I limit the XLim and YLim when the function executes, since its changing every time I change the coordinates with the list?  I've also edited my post since I am now having problems with my `guiToggle` callback function.

Comment: `hold` acts on an `axes`, so you have to pass a handle to your axes to `guitoggle`. You should be able to set the x and y ranges when you create your axes: `...'YLim', [-4,4], 'XLim',[-4,4]...`. Lastly, after you create your axes you can draw lines: `line([0,0],[-4,4],...)`. Line takes line style properties such as `LineWidth` to style those lines.

Comment: Actually, since scatter overwrites things like `YLim`, you should set those things after you create the scatter plot.

Comment: Ok, thats good to know.  In this order, this seems to work: create `axes` then `scatter`, then  used the `axis(axes_h, ..., ...)` function to set the X and Y limits using the `axes_h` handle.  This seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try `hold on` after creating the axes.

```
axes_h = axes('Position',[0.1 0.3 0.4 0.5], 'XLim', [-4 4], 'YLim', [-4 4]);
xlabel(axes_h, 'Valence', 'FontSize', 12, 'FontWeight', 'bold');
ylabel(axes_h, 'Arousal', 'FontSize', 12, 'FontWeight', 'bold');
grid('on');
hold on
```